# Help reinstalling an external door threshold

Tags: doors, carpentry

During recent flooding, the threshold for our basement door trapped about 1.5" inches of water in the basement. In an attempt to get it out the threshold was forcibly removed, and now with hurricane season it'd be nice to have it back.

The problems are two-fold:

1. The threshold was nailed into the door frame before the frame was installed in the basement opening. So the nails go from the outside (i.e. their heads are against cement). I might be able to yank the nails, heads and all, through the door framing, but is there a better solution?
2. What is a good way to ensure a nice tight replacement fit? Adding a sealable weep hole under the threshold might help water drain in a future flood, but I want it weather tight other than that hole, both where it butts against the frame and against the floor.

Assume zero budget but a decent array of tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being an easier job than I thought.

1. Yank the nails out entirely, using vice grips. They were square-cut, and the wood was a tiny bit punky, so this was easy.
2. If I was doing this "right", this is where I would have cut out the punky wood and replaced it, but I wasn't.
3. Cut some exterior-grade cedar boards to length, slant the top surface to shed rain, and cut a drip edge under the exterior lip. I couldn't find 6/4ths board so I doubled up a 1x6. I am slightly concerned about warping here, but this was a cheap fix.
4. Glue the boards in place using construction adhesive.
5. There is no 5. You could finish them if you want, but the cedar should hold up by itself.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding #1 correctly, you have the business end of nails sticking out of your door frame right now, and you can't get to the heads? You could use a cut-off wheel with a dremel to take care of that.

Comment: Yeah, that'd've worked. I ended up using vice grips...turns out they were square-cut nails(!) anyway so they pulled easily. Now, to figure out the glue...